# How to get the type defined in a GraphQL FieldDefinition using the C++ libgraphqlparser?

Tags: c++, graphql

I am using Facebook's libgraphqlparser library to interact with GraphQL ASTs in C++. I am trying to determine the specific `type` of a `FieldDefinition`, which could be a `ListType`, a `NamedType` etc., using code like this:

```
bool isListType (FieldDefinition * fieldDef) {
  if (ListType* lt = dynamic_cast<ListType*>(fieldDef->getType())) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

However, there is the following error on `fieldDef`:

```
the operand of a pointer dynamic_cast must be a pointer to a complete class type
```

Is there another way to test the specific class of what `getType` returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an `AstVisitor` subclass that overrides `visitNamedType`, `visitListType`, and `visitNonNullType` and records which of those three methods was called first in order to do the type check. (See `AstVisitor.h`.) Note that `ListType` and `NonNullType` contain other types! You can also just put your logic for handling each kind of type right in the visitor, which will probably be more convenient if it's possible.